Why are so many philosophers against epiphenomenalism?
Is it because in our every day experience, we feel as if we are causally influencing things? But if that’s the case, intuition also tells us that we have free will, and yet many philosophers do not believe in free will or even find it incoherent.
Epiphenomenalism, as a reminder, is that consciousness is a byproduct of physical processes or may be directly connected to physical processes but doesn’t have any causal power. What exactly is the problem here?
We have some level of evidence that physical processes generate consciousness already given that it doesn’t seem to exist without the brain for example. Thus, this implies a dependence on the physical, but without a dependence of the physical on consciousness. As such, why would we expect conscious processes to play a causal role anyways?

SEP details various arguments against epiphenomenalism.  However, I believe that epiphenomenalism is popular amongst neuroscientists.

We have some level of evidence that physical processes generate consciousness already given that it doesn’t seem to exist without the brain for example - Some dualists may object to this by appealing to anecdotal evidence from near-death experiences, past-life experiences, out-of-body experiences, etc. Whether this evidence is compelling or not is debatable, of course.

Because it posits a superfluous entity. If one does not trust our intuitions on what consciousness does then why trust them on its existence as traditionally understood? Both are tainted by biases of ingrained folk psychology and, under epiphenomenalism, consciousness is an idle wheel anyway. A form of physicalism that either reduces it to physics or dismisses it as illusion is a more attractive option.

@Conifold We don’t intuit that consciousness exists though: it’s an even truer form of “self evident” than other intuitions since even having an intuition implies you’re conscious, so that analogy doesn’t work. For similar reasons, it makes no sense to call a self evident thing superfluous. It may be superfluous with respect to causality under epiphenomenalism but not superfluous with respect to its very existence.

Sentimental emphasis on 'self-evidence' does not impress philosophers much, and physicalists interpret "you’re conscious" in ways that make epiphenomenal consciousness superfluous. For illusionists, it is a an artifact of self-representation, for reductionists, it is a physical process under a misleading description, which is causally efficacious after all.

@Conifold only a subset of the 4% of philosophers who are eliminativists are illusionists so clearly, it is impressing almost all of them: https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/5010. Although I wouldn't use the term impress since again, consciousness's existence is obvious

"Clearly"? 52% are listed as physicalists in that same poll, reductionism is just more popular than eliminativism. Neither functionalism nor identity theory in the answer choices to the linked question are particularly 'self-evident' either. Other positions may well be held for all sorts of reasons aside from 'self-evidence' as well.

@Conifold Physicalists don't deny consciousness. So I'm assuming you just misread what I said. "We don’t intuit that consciousness exists though: it’s an even truer form of “self evident” than other intuitions since even having an intuition implies you’re conscious"

Even non-eliminativist physicalists deny consciousness that can be epiphenomenal, as it is identical to physical processes in extension. And they put little value in "self-evident" with whatever epithets added, as their view hardly is so.

@Conifold Did I say that physicalists don’t deny consciousness that can be epiphenomenal? I said “Physicalists don't deny consciousness”

You seem not to believe in free will. But it can exist even in the a deterministic universe. See [block universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time). But mainly, see the deep, VERY metaphorical Monkees movie about this, Head— or the 3 mins starting here. They realized that they are fictional characters, and they're trying to break out to free will. They are trapped in a black box. When he says, "Don't you see? It doesn't matter if we're in the box," THAT'S the key. That's the answer. Many years ago, that scene changed my life.

The main problem with epiphenomenalism (from a philosophical perspective) is that if epiphenomenalism is true then all of philosophy is void and meaningless. All morality and ethics are void and meaningless; all thoughts and intuitions are void and meaningless; all poetry and art is void and meaningless… It's a non-starter as a position.
Though it is not (to my knowledge) cast this way, epiphenomenalism is a stringent form of nihilism, insisting that all human values are just fog on a mirror. One can proclaim this position easily enough, but there is literally nothing one can do with this position, because anything one might take from this position will just be a mental epiphenomenon that (by definition) has no effect on the world at all.
We cannot argue with a position that asserts that all argument is meaningless and void. All we can do is shrug and go do something else.

I heartily disagree. I think that epiphenomenalism and hence the belief in a lack of agency, will profoundly affect how we think about morality and what that will mean for our  broken justice system. We once burnt witches at the stake. People shrugged and went to do something else. I am glad we no longer do that.

@Philomath: I question your logic. If we lack agency, how can we think or do anything? If we lack agency, then witches will be burned and 'justice' will not be served, because justice is a choice.  It we lack agency, then what's the point of arguing a point? Think it through…

We assume agency because we see it in other minds. We even see it in a chess computer. We say: They tried to capture my Queen! Of course there was no 'trying', the computer was merely executing an algorithm. We see agency everywhere because it makes sense, it is a useful heuristic. We think we have agency because it is part of the model in our brain. This is why we think we have free will. And this is why we think we have a choice. It's an elaborate narrative that is consistent with our model of the world, but a model that I think is ultimately illusory.

And as to what's the point of arguing a point if we have no agency? It's like sitting and listening to the couple at the next table having an argument. Not nice. So then why don't you stop listening? Because you can't. We are slaves of our punishment reward system. Without dopamine you would probably not have bothered checking this comment.

@Philomath: Like I said, an absolute non-starter as a philosophical argument.  If I accept the premise as true then we are reduced to something animalistic, things that makes scrawling marks on each other's computer screens that lack intrinsic meaning, do that because we have no choice; an intrinsically idiotic situation. If I don't accept it, then the argument itself is intrinsically idiotic.  I have an intrinsic experience of 'mind' as effectual: e.g.,the creation of the computers we're on. For what reason should I disregard that evidence?

Conscious experiences having no physical effects says nothing about the truth of what they imply. A thought may not move the table or even my hand, but it may be about a statement in the world that is true nevertheless, thus resulting in meaning. So I actually fail to see how this has anything to do with nihilism whatsoever

@Syed: Computers don't grow on trees (i.e., are not naturally occurring items in the world). They are a physical manifestation of a set of ideas. Epiphenomenalism would tell us that ideas have no effect on the world, and thus that computers are a product of some biophysical processes which also (incidentally) produce the ideas we have about computers: i.e., that computers actually do grow on metaphorical trees, we just mistakenly think otherwise. That is nihilism: the rejection of human value and meaning.

@TedWrigley they are not a manifestation of ideas. They are a manifestation of physical things that correspond to those ideas, in this case the physical wiring of your brain that corresponds to those ideas. You still have not shown how exactly something immaterial affects something material

@Syed: I'm not trying to show that; that's a goal for neuroscientists, not philosophers. I'm just trying to show that the logic of epiphenomenalism is at best self-defeating and at worst stubbornly ridiculous.

@Syed: Let's be clear: the idea of a computer and the physical fact of a computer are related; physical computers did not exist until people thought about them. Either that relationship is (1) causal (people thought about computers and translated those thoughts into physical constructions through some unknown process), or (2) epiphenomenal (the non-cognitive process by which computers came into existence also created thoughts about computers, through some unknown process). Could (2) be true? Possibly. Is (2) sensible reasoning? God, no, please, it's ridiculously convoluted.

@TedWrigley physical computers also did not exist without the physical nature of humans coming about. As mentioned, everything you claimed that could only be explained by consciousness, can be explained instead by the physical processes corresponding to that consciousness. And without offering an explanation for how a conscious experience affects the physical and sidelining that to the job of neuroscientists, means that your claims are ultimately based on nothing.

@Syed: LOL: My claims are based on the experience of consciousness, which precedes and underlies this entire conversation. That's evidence; what have you got? But let me be clear: if you choose to believe that all of your mental processes are purely epiphenomenal and impotent, then I see no reason to continue this discussion.  I prefer not to talk with non-sentient objects. That's my choice. When you decide to be sentient, let me know.

@TedWrigley what determines your choice or your next thought? Good luck making sense of the idea that you think before you think your next thought

You can't argue with someone who is incapable of not arguing.

@TedWrigley If we lack agency, then what's the point of arguing a point? .... and it is sort of fun to watch you arguing a point with someone who has no point in arguing their point!

@Stewart: Well, I choose to believe in agency, so I've gotta give it a try.   But sometimes it turns into that old Monty Python skit ("I'd like to have an argument, please"), and then I just have to call it a day.

@Syed What determines your choice or your next thought?  I do. Me. That centre "awareness of awareness" unit which is pure abstract.

@Stewart In order to make any choice behind anything, you need to think about that choice. What causes that thought?

@Syed That's not true. You can make a choice without thinking.

Epiphenomenalism was at one point in the 50s and 60s pretty popular in philosophy of mind.  I recall my phil of Mind textbook in the 70s was mostly epiphenomenalists.  And it is under a bit of a renaissance now -- with Chalmers, Jackson, and Kim all epiphenomenalists.
But yes, there are a lot of criticisms.
Materialist leaning physicalists do not like that epiphenomenalism is dualist.  There is a lot of anti-dualism rhetoric in philosophy, and being an epiphenomenalist puts one in that bullseye.
Epiphenomenalism has all the complexity of two-way dualism.  One must expalin a second substrate/plane, and one needs interaction between the material and the mind planes.  AND, while epiphenomenalism does not need the other way interaction laws, it DOES need explanation for why the interaction is only one way -- which is no simpler.  The "simplicity" argument for materialism was severely undercut when materialism was refuted by Einstein, and "physicalism" is itself immensely complex (particularly the emergent forms, which are more complex than dualism), but there is still some affection for it.
There are also several powerful counter-evidences.

We have delusions, and at times our minds are blank. So there is no "necessity" for mental events to track with physical ones.  Yet mostly they do.  Why?  Under evolutionary variance, one should expect even if minds were initially in sync with bodies, that they would gradually go out of sync due to mutations.  The only way they can stay in sync, is if minds are causal, and their relevance is selected for by evolution.

We can communicate about our mental life.  Under epiphenomenalism, there is no causal relation between our having a thought, and what we then say about our thoughts.  We could not communicate about our mental life, if it were not causal. We could also not perform experiments to establish NCCs, or ask people about their pain level, or preferences etc. and expect any useful data. Basically every empirical interaction requires that epiphenomenalism not be true.



First, I'm not sure why you're using the word interaction here since that implies causality. It's moreso that physical things generate consciousness and conscious experiences don't generate anything physical: I wouldn't really call this an interaction atleast not in the normal sense of things.

In regards to communication, the physical circuits that correspond to an image of the earth for example, generate the image in your head. This is stored in the physical circuits that correspond to memory. These circuits are then recalled generating similar conscious experiences that then cause physical circuits that correspond to the impulse to want to communicate and then result in communication where I tell someone that I am currently imagining earth. What's the problem here?

Syed -- "generate" is a causal interaction.  What, exactly, is generated?  When? When is something else generated,?  Exactly WHAT "something else"?  When is nothing generated.  Etc.  You need a full set of interaction laws.

In regards to communication, how do you study consciousness and determine its interaction laws?  You have postulated that consciousness is non-causal.  You cannot study it.  You can never have ANY data about it.

generate is a causal interaction from physical to conscious: and to answer the further questions: we don't know. But we sure as hell have a lot of evidence indicating the dependence of consciousness upon the physical: such as the fact we experience long states of a lack of consciousness in sleep, or when we die. Where is any evidence at all for the opposite?

Every moment when I have a thought, then act on it, is an example of consciousness being causal on the physical.

Or the unconscious physical machinery causing the thought is connected to the same machinery causing the action that follows that thought

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Since when is Chalmers an epiphenomenalist?

@YechiamWeiss Chalmers is a dualist, who holds that matter is causally closed.  Therefore he is an epiphenomenalist.  Kim cited Chalmer's epiphenomenalism as a credibility justification for his own epiphenomenalism when he adopted dualism in Physicalism or something Near Enough

@Dcleve in The Conscious Mind Chalmers explicitly distance himself from epiphenomenalism.

@YechiamWeiss  Non-interactive dualism IS epiphenomenalism!  I last read TCM ~2 decades ago, but I concluded from it that Chalmers was arguing for epiphenomenalism.
Kim did so too, from subsequent Chalmers papers.

Your question is the answer.
Epiphenomenalism is the idea that mental events are caused by physical events, but do not cause physical effects themselves. It then follows that  the brain should not have knowledge of the mind. But your question on this SE asks about epiphenomenalism which shows that we have knowledge of epiphenomenalism. We then have to conclude that our brains do know about the mind. Therefore, epiphenomenalism can not be true.
This objection is known as the argument of self-stultification.
There are more arguments and they mostly have to do with the heinous consequences of epiphenomenology, namely the fact that it undermines our evident agency in action and precludes our substantial self knowledge.
Jerry Fodor ((1990). A theory of content and other essays) put it more eloquently than I can:

If it isn’t literally true that my wanting is causally responsible for my reaching, and my itching is causally responsible for my scratching, and my believing is causally responsible for my saying …, if none of that is literally true, then practically everything I believe about anything is false and it’s the end of the world.

Fodor also coined the term epiphobia, the fear that one's views imply epiphenomenalism.
For what it is worth: I am a staunch epiphenomenalist. But that was not the question.

"evident agency in action" how evident really is this? Do you even choose your thoughts? In order to choose your thoughts, you'd have to first think about which thoughts you will next think: this sounds circular and obviously false. Thoughts come from nowhere even in experience, and are likely better explained by the unconscious physical machinery generating them. I also don't see how the brain shouldn't have knowledge of the mind just because consciousness can't cause physical effects

@Syed I am afraid you misunderstood me. This is not my position. I was merely answering your question. Your question was: why are so many philosophers against epiphenomenalism? It was not: what do you think? I mentioned that in my last sentence.

But to steelman the opposition's argument: If the brain consists of atoms and molecules and these give rise to conscious eperience then how do the atoms and molecules 'know' that, if that experience can not be sensed / detected? If there is a so called neural correlate of consciousness, then if it fires and 'the lights went on', then how does another part of the brain know that something very peculiar happend: namely that the lights came on?

We have knowledge of epiphenomenalism. We then have to conclude that our brains do know about the mind. This does not follow at all. You have identified we with our brains. That's something that needs support. What it means for me to have knowledge, and for my brain to know something, are two completely separate things. It's even two different usages of the word "know". A brain can only "know" something in the same way the same way a clock "knows" what time it is. A clock doesn't know what time is, or what time means. Neither does a brain.

@Stewart Of course the brain itself has no knowledge, just as no clock has any knowledge. The brain is just atoms and molecules. But it gives rise to mental states or the mind. If I argued that having knowledge of epiphenomenalism is enough to prove downward causation then it could be argued that it is just a mental state (an epiphenomenon) knowing about other mental states (epiphenomena). The argument therefore needs to show that mental states affect brain states. The brain states subsequently give rise to other mental states including the one that is knowledge about mental states.

@Philomath it gives rise to mental states or the mind.  We don't know this. You are using your conclusion as a starting point. I believe the mind causes the brain, not the other way around. But it's a difficult thing to prove in either direction.

@Stewart That's interesting. You mean as in Analytic Idealism?

@Philomath I have not heard the term "Analytic Idealism" before, so I'm not sure. I need to look it up.  To be more specific about how I see things: The mind can affect the body (of which the brain is part), but also the body can affect the mind. But the degree to which these things happen is different for each individual, which is why you get so many different philosophical viewpoints. Your reality of mind/brain interaction is different to my reality. But fundamentally, I think the mind is more senior. When the body affects the mind, it is because the person, the "owner" of that mind has said

@Philomath "The body+brain affects me," and so they do. In other words, the mind is allowing the brain to be cause point. But at any moment the mind can change its mind (change itself, ha ha) and revoke this setup. Whether this is true or real or convincing is different from person to person. But for sure, there are people who can simply decide not to be ill, for example. Or can decide to change their emotion.

Epiphenomenalism contradicts what we have learned concerning nature, through such people as Newton and Darwin.
It contradicts Newton's law of reaction, in that it implies that there could exist cases where causation is asymmetric and non-reversable: X can cause Y but Y cannot cause X. To my knowledge we have yet to find any evidence of such asymmetric causation in nature. What seems to be the case is that if X can impact Y, then Y can impact X, at least in principle. Causality works both ways.
More fundamentally, something that exists as part of this world must exist in some sense as a cause for something else. It must make a difference in this world, otherwise in what sense is it part of it? How could we even ascertain its existence? How could we notice it?
Epiphenomena do not exist, as defined. They have no way of existing, other than as a figment of our imagination, because to exist means to impact other stuff around.
Finally, as a specific biological behavior, conscious thoughts require a Darwinian explanation as per how they emerged, and why they spread and remained a character of a certain population of living organisms throughout a certain evolutionary period. By definition, an epiphenomenon can present no Darwinian advantage, so how come we are not all unconscious beings?
Conscious thoughts must present an advantage to the organism, least they contradict Darwin.

Images in a video game are generated by computer code. The images themselves don’t affect the code: only their representation in code can. The steam of a train is caused by the train engine but has no impact on the train. There’s an example of asymmetric causation.

@Syed the steam is what moves the train.The image on the screen is what the player uses to navigate and play the game and input new code into the machine.

“Huxley (1874), who held the view, compared mental events to a steam whistle that contributes nothing to the work of a locomotive. James (1879), who rejected the view, characterized epiphenomenalists’ mental events as not affecting the brain activity that produces them “any more than a shadow reacts upon the steps of the traveller whom it accompanies”.“

@Syed the steam blown by the wistle  cannot be used by the engine. People get scared by their own shadow.

Stumbled here from general, so apologies for missing the obvious, but surely asymmetric causation is the norm? An egg is caused by a chicken, which certainly wasn't caused by that specific egg.

@Uzai That egg could hatch, and the resulting chick could cause joy and or pain to her mother. Chicken don't lay eggs for nothing.

@Olivier5 Ok, so rather than "cause" meaning "brings about", which is how I was interpreting it, "cause" here instead means "affects in some way"? In that case I suppose I agree, since any two things that both exist could conceivably interact.

@Uzai Okay. My point is precisely that IF any two things that both exist could conceivably interact, THEN nothing that exists can be described as "non-causal".
